# Is this called Overloading?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overloading

I have wo methods with the same name but different parameter types and different return types.

```
public class TestOverloading {

    public void display(){
        System.out.println("Inside display method of TestOverloading class");
    }

    public int display(int i){
        System.out.println("Inside display method  of TestOverloading class values is "+ i);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Output:
The following code works fine no errors in JDK 1.6.

Is it called Overloading? If not, why not?

Comment: It is. Several methods with the same name are overloads. You could even add `display(Object obj)`

Comment: But how does it satisfy overloading definition? "Overloading in Java occurs when two or more methods in the same class have the exact same name but different parameters".

Comment: Both display methods have different return types. Will they be considered overloaded methods or independent methods of class?

Comment: They will, overloading cares about the parameters, not the return types.

Answer (score 4):

If methods has same name and different parameters they are called overloaded methods. Return type does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

yes it is overloading.

> In a class, there can be several methods with the same name. However
>   they must have different signature. The signature of a method is
>   comprised of its name, its parameter types and the order of its
>   parameter. The signature of a method is not comprised of its return
>   type nor its visibility nor its thrown exceptions. In common word "In
>   java defines two or more method within the same class that shares the
>   same names but differents parameters". It is called the overloading
>   methods.

Comment: public void display() throws Arithmatic Exception and void display(int i) throws Exception is also overloading. You mean to say : Although they throwing different exceptions but they satisfy basic definition ?Correct ?